# Вывод русских или английских слов строки

Tags: python

Как вывести все русские или английские слова в строке. Пример строки:  'apple яблоко, car', желаемый результат при выводе: яблоко или applecar

Comment: Я не совсем понял вопрос, вам необходимо вывести все английские или русские слова ? Или же удалить в строке определенное слово и вывести это слово ?

Comment: Мне нужно либо удалить все русские слова, либо вывести только английские слова, что-то из этого.

Comment: так вы опять вопрос ищете в интернете, а не ответ. свой код надо приводить в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если формализовать понятие "слово" до непрерывной последовательности букв какого-то алфавита, то можно воспользоваться [регулярными выражениями](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

***Пример:***

```py
import re

en = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+')
ru = re.compile('[а-яА-Яё]+')

s = 'apple яблоко, car'

words_en = en.findall(s)
words_ru = ru.findall(s)

print(''.join(words_en))
print(''.join(words_ru))
```

***stdout:***

```py
applecar
яблоко
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли.

Comment: не забывайте о букве "ё" - она не попадает в диапазон `'[а-я]'` )

Comment: @MaxU Точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Так как ответ уже был дан, лишь добавлю пример без использования библиотеки re

Код:

```
line = 'apple яблоко, car'

russian_alphabet = set('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')
english_alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

russian_words = [i for i in line.split() if not(russian_alphabet.isdisjoint(i.lower()))]
english_words = [i for i in line.split() if not(english_alphabet.isdisjoint(i.lower()))]

print(russian_words)
print(english_words)
```

При выполнении:

```
['яблоко,']
['apple', 'car']
```

Comment: И вам спасибо).